# How to include _AFXDLL compiler option while compiling in visual studio 8 and "USING MFC as a Static Library"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I need to add translation for an old VS C++ application. This application and all the .lib files it implicitly links to are compiled by using MFC as Static Library.

To translate the app into other languages I need to include resource dll's explicitly. I make use of the object `CDynLinkLibrary` defined in the `#include <afxdll_.h>`.

Now the problem is I get the error message `fatal error C1189: #error :  file must be compiled with _AFXDLL` when I include the header `afxdll_.h`.

Changing my project to use MFC as a shared library is not an option due to many reasons. How can I work around with this limitations?

Comment: You don't need CDynLinkLibrary to use resource DLLs.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Can you be more elaborate please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `CDynLinkLibrary`, use `LoadLibraryEx` to load the DLL and call `AfxSetResourceHandle` to start using the resources from that DLL.

Comment: But that way you don't have resource chaining, so you need to duplicate all the resources of the exe, even the ones that will not be different.